# Extracting values of a dictionary which is in a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, pycharm

[image]Please see the attached picture of what I am trying to achieve.

I just want the output as showing and not change the list completely. I tried loop  was able extract only the first pair of value however no luck after that.

Hope I was able to explain.

Comment: ** I am reading and returning the data from a list

Comment: Can you show the code you tried that didn't work? And can you please include your data as text and not an image in your post?

Comment: subDomain_list ** already iterating and getting this list

---------------------------------------------------

subDomain_list = subDomain_Function(which.get())
-------what I have tried
newsublist = []
for key,values in subDomain_list[0].items():
 tempdict = {}
 tempdict = values
 newsublist.append(tempdict)
master.extend(newsublist) ** After commenting below line
--------------------------------
master.extend(subDomain_list) - this is what is returning now that I have showin

Comment: Please put that code into the body of your post - comments on StackOverflow absolutely destroy any formatting or sense if you're trying to show more than a short line of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have a list of dictionaries and only want to print `subdomain` is that correct? Then it's simple:

```
for d in dict_list: # Let's say "dict_list" is the list you're working on
    print(f"{d['subdomain']}:{d['ports']}")
```

As others have pointed out do not put pictures it really makes things harder for those who want to help you. Even my answer is just a guess at what you tried to explain and I might get it all wrong.

**Edited**: Alright I missed the column, in fact you wanted `subdomain:ports` . I fixed it if you don't mind the hacky format using f-string.

Comment: Hi, both the subdomain and the port. So in each entry there is a key:value,key:value'. what i need is value:value –

Comment: TY !!! I used a new list then used your code to put it in a temp dictionary and then appended the new list with the dictionary and returned the new list. And Viola. Once again TY !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!